# Adding JSON objects to existing JSON File

Tags: java, json, kotlin

So I've recently been tasked with creating a utility which will allow easy addition of JSON to a .json file via the gson library. I've coded this in Kotlin:

```
fun addObject(filePath: String, name: String, values: Array<Array<String>>) {
try {

    var writer: JsonWriter = JsonWriter(FileWriter(File(filePath)))
    writer.beginObject()
    writer.name(name)
    writer.beginObject()
    for(item in values){
        writer.name(item[0]).value(item[1])
    }
    writer.endObject()
    writer.endObject()

    writer.close()

    println("[JSONUtil] Wrote object successfully!")

} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
}
```

I used a 2 Dimensional array to allow the user to add different objects with any number of values in said object. For instance, you would run it like so:

```
addObject("C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\JsonUtility\\output.json", "GENERAL", 
arrayOf(arrayOf("POS_X","2"), arrayOf("POS_Y","4")))
```

This creates the following JSON:

```
{"GENERAL":{"POS_X":"2","POS_Y":"4"}}
```

This is how it was intended and works, my issue is that upon running the function again it completely overwrites the previous JSON in the file, and this is obviously bad.

My questions are:

- How can I add new JSON objects inside the entire file, or at specific points, like "addObject("GENERAL", ...)" for this example?
- How can I make this better?

I'm fairly new to Kotlin and have been coding in Java mostly, so Java solutions are fine as I'm sure I'll be able to convert it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: New Code, no idea how to implement it:

```
fun UpdateJson(path: String, name: String, value: String){
    var gson = Gson()
    var reader: FileReader = FileReader(File(path))

    val type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.type
    println("Type: " + type.toString())
    println("Existing Json: ${gson.fromJson<Map<String,String>>
    (JsonReader(reader), type)}")
    var existingJson: Map<String, String> = 
    gson.fromJson<Map<String,String>>(JsonReader(reader), type)
    existingJson.put(name, value)
    FileWriter(File(path)).use({ writer -> 
    writer.write(gson.toJson(existingJson)) })
}
```

Comment: `catch (e: IOException = java.io.IOException)` is wrong, should be just `catch (e: IOException)`. Or you can remove catch at all.

Comment: Thank you, will make the change. Got any more tips?

Comment: You need to first read the json, then add new element, last store it.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Adding the new element is what I'm having difficulty with. How can I make it so the user can specify an object to add the new element to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to, as @KrisRoofe suggested, read the json, then add an element. I would do this by [converting the existing json in the file to a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/how-can-i-convert-json-to-a-hashmap-using-gson). Since you don't actually care about the existing json, all you want to do is add a new entry to that Map. Once you do that, simply write the new Map to the File. You can do this like so:

```
public class UpdateJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        addObject("example.json", "GENERAL", arrayOf(arrayOf("POS_X","2"), arrayOf("POS_Y","4")));
    }

    private static void addObject(String fileName, String newObjName, String newObjValue) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, String> existingJson = gson.fromJson(new JsonReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName))), type);
        existingJson.put(newObjName, newObjValue);
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(fileName))) {
            writer.write(gson.toJson(existingJson));
        }
    }

    private static String arrayOf(String s1, String s2) {
        return "[" + s1 + ", " + s2 + "]";
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The above solution is a Java solution. There seems to be an issue with the `Type` in Kotlin.

1. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin) has a workaround by using `object:`
2. Also, note that to use reflection with Kotlin, you need a separate jar, according to [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html)'

EDIT 2: Provided Kotlin Answer:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    addObject("example.json", "GENERAL", arrayOf(arrayOf("POS_X", "2"), arrayOf("POS_Y", "4")))
}


fun addObject(path: String, name: String, value: String) {
    val gson = Gson()
    val reader: FileReader = FileReader(File(path))
    val type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.type
    System.out.println("Type: " + type.toString())
    val existingJson = gson.fromJson<Map<String, String>>(JsonReader(reader), type)
    System.out.println("Existing Json: ${existingJson}")
    val newJsonMap = existingJson.plus(Pair(name, value))
    FileWriter(File(path)).use(
        { writer -> writer.write(gson.toJson(newJsonMap)) }
    )
}

fun arrayOf(s1: String, s2: String): String {
    return "[$s1, $s2]"
}
```

Comment: Hmm, having some difficulty with the Type class, seems to not play nice with Kotlin because the Java to Kotlin conversion removes the "Type" type and replaces it with "object", which then results in an inference error. Any alternatives to Type?

Comment: just change it back to Type, it works fine in Kotlin.  @CoalCoding you are asking people to write your code instead of one specific question.

Comment: If I change it back to type it says "unresolved reference "type" at the ".type" it converts it to at the end. ".getType()" is the same.

Comment: According to the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html), "On the Java platform, the runtime component required for using the reflection features is distributed as a separate JAR file (kotlin-reflect.jar). "

Comment: Will check that out now. The only alternative seems to be "KType", which appears to have a different usage.

Comment: Also see the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin)

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the issue.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'm not done yet unfortunately. I don't really understand how to implement this. I'm sorry I'm a bit of a noob. I've previously been using simple objects and .name and .value and stuff. How do I add stuff to this? How do I combine this with my previous code.

Comment: Getting this error when I attempt to use: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: gson.fromJson<Map<String…eader(File(path))), type) must not be null @Ishnark

Comment: Could you add to your post the current version of your code?

Comment: `fun UpdateJson(path: String, name: String, value: String){
    var gson = Gson()
    var reader: FileReader = FileReader(File(path))

    val type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.type
    println("Type: " + type.toString())
    println("Existing Json: ${gson.fromJson<Map<String,String>>(JsonReader(reader), type)}")
    var existingJson: Map<String, String> = gson.fromJson<Map<String,String>>(JsonReader(reader), type)
    existingJson.put(name, value)
    FileWriter(File(path)).use({ writer -> writer.write(gson.toJson(existingJson)) })
}

`
@Ishnark

Comment: Edited post for Kotlin

Comment: "plus" is not a function and if you try "put" , it requires a string rather than a Pair of strings. Assume you mean this: `val newJsonMap = existingJson.put(name,value)` however that gives you the following error: `Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 13 path $.
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:891)
 at JsonUtilityKt.addObjects(JsonUtility.kt:45)
 at JsonUtilityKt.main(JsonUtility.kt:15)
`

Comment: That's interesting -> IntelliJ tells me `put` doesn't exist, but `plus` does.

Comment: We most likely have different versions of gson, I am also using IntelliJ. My version is 2.6.2.

Comment: `existingJson` is a`Map<String, String>`. Shouldn't be gson related. Also it looks like `plus` has been in both 1.0.x and 1.1.x versions of the language. Maybe I'm missing something [here's what I'm looking at](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/). Also I'm using `gson-2.8.0.jar`

Comment: Ahh the issue was I was using the Java Map package. I still get this error though: `Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 13 path $.`

Comment: I got the IllegalStateException by calling `gson.fromJson<Map<String, String>>(JsonReader(reader), type)` twice. Which is why in my code, instead of calling it twice, the second time I called it (in the print statement) I called it by `existingJson`

Comment: I only used it once and I still get the error with some existing json in there.

Comment: Also if there is no json in there it is null and doesn't add anything.

Comment: An empty json file, to be considered an object, must atleast have `{}`

Comment: That fixed my issue. The error was from using the incorrect format. Everything works now and I realise I've been pretty stupid not reading the gson documentation. Thanks for all the help.