# Gson toJson and ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin) question, I would like to convert an object (actually, it is a API response from retrofit) to a json string, so it would be simpler to store it somewhere.

The response structure is something like these:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "count": 0,
    "type": "string"
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "obj1": {
        "param1": "s1",
        "param2": "s2"
      },
      "obj2": {
        "param3": 0,
        "param4": 0,
        "param5": 0
      },
      "obj3": 0,
      "obj4": "27/12/2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using retrofit2, I have the results array stored in a `List<MyResponse.Result>` and that's the parameter I'm passing to `Gson().toJson`, like so:

```
var contentResponse: String = ""
try{
    this.contentResponse.plus(Gson().toJson(response))
} catch (e: Exception){
    Log.e("Gson error", e.toString())
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting no exception but my `contentResponse` keeps empty. I`ve tried to use the method in the question mentioned above, but got the same outcome. Any advises?

PS: If there is an easier way to get the retrofit response in a String, it could help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable in JVM. Calling

```
this.contentResponse.plus(Gson().toJson(response))
```

is equivalent to

```
this.contentResponse + (Gson().toJson(response))
```

This way you can see better that you are not assiging the result to anything. Change it to

```
this.contentResponse = this.contentResponse.plus(Gson().toJson(response))
```