# How do I parse JSON from shared preference to an array using GSON (Kotlin)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, sharedpreferences

I have parsed an array to `JSON` and stored it in `shared preferences` but how do I get it back from JSON to an `array`?

```
var savedFavRecipes: ArrayList<String>? = null

var sp = context.getSharedPreferences("FAV", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

savedFavRecipes?.add(recipeArray!![counterX!!].recipeKey!!) //Stores a string in an array

var myJSON = Gson().toJson(savedFavRecipes) //parse the array to JSON

var spStorage = sp.edit()

spStorage.putString("KEY", myJSON).apply() //Store in Shared preference
```

Now to retrieve it back from shared preference and into an array.

```
//GET FROM SHARED PREFERENCE PARCED FROM JSON
var getArray = sp.getString("KEY", null)

if(getArray != null) {
    var newArray = Gson().fromJson(getArray, RecipesActivity::class.java)

    Log.d("TAG", " " + newArray[0]) //Crashes
}
```

Setting datatype seems to reveal a problem:

```
var newArray: ListArray<String> = Gson().fromJson(getArray, RecipesActivity::class.java)
```

Says `List required, found RecipesActivity`

Think I don't fully get how to do this. For example, I don't understand the point of the last argument `RecipesActivity::class.java`

***UPDATE*** 
Tried

```
var newArray: ArrayList<String> = Gson().fromJson(getArray, ArrayList<String>().javaClass)
```

but it crashes with a null point exception.

Comment: Documentation of method `fromJson`: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-. If you want to get an object of type `T`, the last argument must be the class of `T`. In your case, you want to get a `ListArray<String>` but you are passing `RecipesActivity::class.java`.

Comment: Tried changing it to `ListArray<String>` but then it says unresolved reference...

Comment: Try this: `var newArray: List<String> = Gson().fromJson<List<String>>(getArray, object : TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.type)`. Info from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33381385/1861769. And I suggest creating the `inline fun` that is shown in the answer.