# Gson adds "root", "entrySet", "values" fields after deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, kotlin, gson, assertj

I have the following JSON String:

```
[
  {
    "id": 23425,
    "mailboxGroupId": 6659,
    "statusCode": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "id": 23425,
    "groupId": 6659,
    "statusCode": "INACTIVE"
  }
]
```

I want to deserialize it into a list of two objects of Kotlin data class type:

```
val myList: List<Foo> = Gson().fromJson(response, ArrayList<Foo>().javaClass)
```

Next, I need to compare with AssertJ these two objects and assert that all fields except for `statusCode` are equal:

```
assertThat(myList.first()).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(myList.last(), "statusCode")
```

But when I run the test, I get an assertion error:

```
Expecting values:
<.....>
in fields:
  <["root", "entrySet", "values"]>
```

Looks like Gson adds `"root", "entrySet", "values"` during the deserialization, but I can't understand how can I exclude them?

Or I don't need to exclude them and just need to change my assertion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use TypeToken + generics with Gson in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin)

Comment: maybe try to ignore "root", "entrySet", "values" fields along with "statusCode" ?
not great but if it works ...

Comment: @JoelCostigliola well, I tried to ignore "root, "entrySet" and "values" as well and it works. But when I remove "statusCode" from the list of ignored fields, then test doesn't fail. So I assume that POJOs are under the `root` field and thus the whole object is ignored when I ignore the `root` field.

Comment: likely so Vitalii.
If that is possible, you could try another approach and asserting directly the JSON data with https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit wich supports ignoring values