# How to send MutableList<Point> from intent to another in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to send `MutableList<Point>` array list as Extra from Intent to another in kotlin.
Declaring the list:

```
private var thePoints: MutableList<Point> = mutableListOf()
```

and here is how I add items to it:

```
                if (startStationPoint != null) {
                    thePoints.add(startStationPoint)
                }
```

And am using this method to send it to the other Activity:

```
            navigationActivity.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
                "thePoints",
                thePoints)
```

It gives me this error:

```
Type mismatch:
Required: ArrayList<out Parcelable>!
Found: MutableListM<Point>
```

as am using `putParcelableArrayListExtra` as there is no such thing to put points arraylist extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error explains you are using as argument a mutable list but you have to use an array

```
thePoints.toList().toTypedArray()
```

I'm not sure if that will work because Point can not meet the conditions

You could create a class representing the point

```
data class SerializablePoint(val longitude: Long, val latitude: Long) : Serializable
```

And then use `.map` to convert them.

Or you could do the same with parceleable.

Another options is to try `Pair` which is Kt API, but again I don't know if parcealability or serializability conditions are complied.

To figure it out ctrl+click on any of those classes and see if in any point implements serializable or parceleable, otherwise transforming to a custom class will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Google Gson to convert the object to a string and then pass it as a string.
from the receiving end convert the string to your original object.

Refer this ->

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33381385/9901309

Comment: Problem shouldnt need a dependency as solution