# kotlin variable type changed in runtime

Tags: android, variables, kotlin, gson

i have strange problem in android and kotlin.
the problem is i define variable with `ArrayList<Long>` type but in runtime change to `ArrayList<Double>`

i define my variable like this:

`private var mDivideEntityValue: ArrayList<Long> = arrayListOf()`

and use Gson library to assign value like:

```
// mDivideEntity is string variable store in json array like: ["150","30"]
mDivideEntityValue = Gson().fromJson(mDivideEntity.amounts, ArrayList<Long>()::class.java)
```

after assign `ArrayList<Long>` change to `ArrayList<Double>`

is this kotlin bug? or i miss something?

i use kotlin 1.3.71 and jvm 1.8.

update 0:

[image: kotlin debug arraylist init with ArrayList<Long>]

[image: kotlin debug Arraylist init with gson ArrayList<Long>()::class.java]

[image: Assing section]

Comment: What makes you say that it "change to ArrayList<Double>"?  Could you add some code that shows it doing this?  Please see [How to create a Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RyanM i update question. i define `ArrayList` as `Long`. but in next line change type to double in runtime. i say i define var type and must remain and draw exception if other type assign why i get nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json doesn't have different number types, so by default, all numbers get parsed to a Double. When you pass `ArrayList<Long>` to `fromJson()`, Gson cannot see the `<Long>` type due to type erasure. When you are passing a class type to a Java library, you might as well use `<*>` as the type.

Kotlin lets the returned `ArrayList<Double>` get assigned to your `ArrayList<Long>` property because at runtime it can't tell the difference (type erasure).

However, Arrays do have reified types. This might work (didn't test it):

```
val divideEntityValue = Gson().fromJson(mDivideEntity.amounts, LongArray::class.java)
```

That will give you a LongArray rather than ArrayList. Alternatively, you should be able to map the returned list to a List:

```
mDivideEntityValue = Gson().fromJson(mDivideEntity.amounts, ArrayList::class.java)
    .map { it.toLong() }
```

Comment: i update question. as i said in question i define `ArrayList` as Long and change type in to `ArrayList<Double>` in  next line. i think kotlin variable have static type and in this case must draw exception. am i wrong?

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. Due to type erasure, an ArrayList has no type at runtime. Kotlin can only warn you at compile time if types don't match. At runtime, it cannot. Since Gson uses reflection to create and populate the list, it does not get checked at compile time. Read up on JVM type erasure for the explanation.

Comment: thanks @Tenfour04. can you edit your answer so i can accept it. i read about  type erasure at https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure and i understand a little about it.

Comment: as you said the problem is JVM type erasure in my case. may copy paste comment in answer.

Comment: I mentioned it in the second paragraph.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin for a third option.