# Convert to list of data class object from JSON string using Gson?

Tags: json, list, kotlin, gson

I have JSON string as below

```
var purchases = "[{\"contentId\":\"861723b2-78e4-42ea-8479-40fa0850c314\",\"purchaseType\":\"RENT\"},{\"contentId\":\"138bc762-b539-4749-8706-de2f0eea4b61\",\"purchaseType\":\"PURCHASE\"}]"
```

I am trying to convert it into list of data class objects

```
val userPurchases: List<UserPurchases> = Gson().fromJson(purchases,List<UserPurchases>)
```

This is my data class

```
data class UserPurchases(
    val contentId: String,
    val purchaseType: String)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by below

```
val purchase: List<UserPurchases> = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(userPurchases, Array<UserPurchases>::class.java).toList()
```