# GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $" - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm trying to parse this JSON string that returns the ids of movies from this api "https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/online-movie-database/" but i get a error

```
[
    "/title/tt1649418/",
    "/title/tt10954984/",
    "/title/tt9114286/",
    "/title/tt10648342/",
    "/title/tt4471908/"
]
```

into this object

```
data class PopularMovies(
    val popularMovies: ArrayList<String>
)
```

but it throws me with

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [TypeToken](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to load the json string into a custom object.

Here is the **Kotlin** example code in your case:

```
val jsonString = "[\n" +
        "    \"/title/tt1649418/\",\n" +
        "    \"/title/tt10954984/\",\n" +
        "    \"/title/tt9114286/\",\n" +
        "    \"/title/tt10648342/\",\n" +
        "    \"/title/tt4471908/\"\n" +
        "]"

val typeToken = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.type
popularMovies = Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<String>>(jsonString, typeToken)
Log.d(TAG, "First string:" + popularMovies[0])
```

Or you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin/33381385#33381385) for various alternatives.